# Naked pointer to unique_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, unique-ptr

I have a structure with a vector and I need to store a pointer to one of its items. With naked  pointers, I'd do like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <unistd.h>

struct A {
    A () {
        v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        uv = &v.front();
    }

    std::vector<int> v;
    int* uv;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << *a.uv << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I can get rid of the naked pointer with `make_shared`:

```
struct A {
    A () {
        v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        uv = std::make_shared<int>(v.front());
    }

    std::vector<int>     v;
    std::shared_ptr<int> uv;
};
```

Since C++11 doesn't implement make_unique yet, how can I do the same thing with a unique_ptr? I tried assigning the front element by making `uv` a `unique_ptr` and calling `uv.reset(&v.front());`, but I get the following error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7f856bc0bcf0: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: That pointer doesn't *own* anything. Don't use a smart pointer for that. Either use a raw pointer or an iterator.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't take pointer from the reference and store it permanently. `&v.front()` is valid only if v is unchanged. Indeed `uv` doesn't point to a memory that needs to be freed.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your intended usage of unique_ptr is canonical. FWIW you can initialise a unique_ptr with the constructor: unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int); Or you can initialise with another unique_ptr, but you must move the data: unique_ptr other(move(ptr)); This is because unique_ptr is move assignable and move constructible, but not copy assignable nor copy constructible. The purpose is to retain ownership, and make it quite clear what is responsible for destroying the object. As you rightly point out, make_unique will be arriving in C++14, until then we are stuck with the old syntax.

Comment: This appears to be an XY problem.  The OP is storing a iterator/pointer to an internal address it does not own (and could potentially be invalid if the state of the vector changes).  Chances are this is really a design problem - what is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The philosophy behind `std::unique_ptr` is that of **ownership**, i.e. it's an object that owns a region of memory, tying the lifetime of the latter to its own.

An `std::vector` follows the same path: it claims ownership of the elements it contains. Thus, when its destructor runs, it triggers the destructors of its elements (if they are user-defined types).

In your case, `v` owns `v.front()`, but you also gave this responsibility to `uv`. Now, **both of them** will try to destroy the same object.

It is better to use a raw pointer here, or (better) an iterator, since it's used as an observer only.

Comment: How do I use an iterator here? just "int uv = v.front()" ?

Comment: `auto uv = v.begin()`?

Comment: But I can't have "auto" as a struct member, since it's not an actual type.